# Terraform AWS - The requested configuration is currently not supported (status code: 400)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I have just getting started with `terraform` using `aws` services.

1. I just created a new user IAM user and given it AdministrativeAccess
2. Copied down the Access Key and Secret and pasted it in *terraform* `instance.tf` file under `provider "aws" {}`
3. Ran the command: `terraform init` and it worked fine.
4. Ran the command: `terraform apply` but in the end it gives me following error:

> aws_instance.example: Creating...
>
> Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested
>   configuration is currently not supported. Please check the
>   documentation for supported configurations.   status code: 400, request
>   id: cf85fdcf-432e-23d3-1233-790cfb2aa33fs
>
> on instance.tf line 7, in resource "aws_instance" "example":    7:
>   resource "aws_instance" "example" {

Here is my `terraform` code:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
  secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
  region     = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0b9bd0b532ebcf4c9"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Any help would be appreciatable,

Cheers :)

Comment: could you show your terraform code?

Comment: I just updated my question with terraform code, also I just created AWS IAM user today, it could be problem on aws side but not sure. Thanks :)

Comment: I think that you missing some parameters like availability_zone, security groups and so on, better check the docs

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me after changing the eu-west-1 to eu-west-2 because for some reason eu-west-1 has no VPC (strangely, [link](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=eu-west-1)). Second thing to change was ami.

Paste the following in `instance.tf` with correct ACCESS and SECRET keys and do `terraform init` and then `terraform apply`. It should work.

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
  secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
  region     = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-031e556ebe95c007e"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I used the wrong AMI ID : I used the "64-bit Arm" arch instead of "64-bit x86".

Using the AMI ID of "64-bit x86" fixes the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best options are to check your AMI and the region. This is not a terraform issue. Its AWS AMI or REGION problem.